# Как отсортировать в алфавитном порядке многоуровневый список?

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, list, список

Нужно отсортировать список на каждом уровне, что у меня получилось ниже, но проблема в том, что DOM-дерево осталось прежним, что совершенно неприемлемо, т.к. после сортировки по алфавиту, подсписки теряют связь с пунктом выше уровнем. Как правильно всё это реализовать? Буду премного благодарен.

```js
  let abc = document.createElement('div');
        abc.id = 'abc';
        document.body.appendChild(abc, document.body.lastChild);
    
        let firstLevelLis = document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li');
    
        let vals1 = [];
    
        for(let i = 0, l = firstLevelLis.length; i < l; i++) {
            vals1.push(firstLevelLis[i].innerHTML);
        };
    
        vals1.sort();
    
        for(let i = 0, l = firstLevelLis.length; i < l; i++) {
            firstLevelLis[i].innerHTML = vals1[i];
        }
    
        let secondLevelLis = document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > ul > li');
    
        let vals2 = [];
    
        for(let i = 0, l = secondLevelLis.length; i < l; i++) {
            vals2.push(secondLevelLis[i].innerHTML);
        };
    
        vals2.sort();
    
        for(let i = 0, l = secondLevelLis.length; i < l; i++) {
            secondLevelLis[i].innerHTML = vals2[i];
        }
    
        let thirdLevelLis = document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > ul > ul > li');
    
        let vals3 = [];
    
        for(let i = 0, l = thirdLevelLis.length; i < l; i++) {
            vals3.push(thirdLevelLis[i].innerHTML);
        };
    
        vals3.sort();
    
        for(let i = 0, l = thirdLevelLis.length; i < l; i++) {
            thirdLevelLis[i].innerHTML = vals3[i];
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Введение в JavaScript</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Размещение скриптов на HTML-страницах</li>
                <li>Синтаксис языка</li>
                <li>Типы данных</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Объект Global</li>
                    <li>Оборачивание (wrapping), изменчивость (mutability)</li>
                    <li>Преобразование типов, основные методы: toString, valueOf</li>
                    <li>Инициализация объектов, массивов и функций</li>
                </ul>
                <li>Переменные и область видимости</li>
                <li>Операторы языка</li>
                <li>Выражения: условия и циклы</li>
                <li>Операторы перехода (label, break, continue, return)</li>
                <li>Исключения и обработка ошибок: try/catch/finally, throw</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Работа с объектами в JavaScript</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Создание объектов</li>
                <li>Доступ к свойствам: опрос, добавление, удаление и перечисление свойств</li>
                <li>Массивы, методы работы с массивами</li>
                <li>Функции и передача параметров</li>
            </ul>
            <li>JavaScript в браузере</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Очередность выполнения скриптов</li>
                <li>DOM: объектная модель документа</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Основные объекты браузера, объект Window</li>
                    <li>Объект Document: поиск и работа с элементами</li>
                    <li>Настройка и изменение стилей документа</li>
                    <li>Обработка событий</li>
                    <li>Графика: элемент canvas</li>
                </ul>
                <li>Работа с формами: валидация данных, регулярные выражения</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </body>
    
      
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного поменял разметку: Соседствующие `ul` c `li` создавали дополнительные сложности... там, где под li должен быть ul - вставил этот ul во внутрь (при желании можно добавить небольшой скрипт, который сам выполнит это изменение).

```js
let ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'); // Получаю только ul вместо ul > li

for (let i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
  // Уже внутри, для каждого ul можно рассматривать его дочерние li.
  let li = [...ul[i].children].sort((a, b) => {
    return a.textContent >= b.textContent ? 1 : -1
  });
  /* ul[i].children возвращает список элементов, но это не обычный массив, у него нет
  метода sort(). Оператор ... позволяет добавлять элементы из списка в массив,
  и сортировать уже его 

  Если хочется поддерживать старые браузеры - можно собрать тот же массив
  через цикл. А с кодом ниже - также, appendChild через цикл. */

  ul[i].append( ...li ); // (*1) 
  /* Тот же оператор ... позволяет сразу передать в качестве аргументов функции 
  все элементы массива. Как-бы через запятые append( li[0], li[1], li[2])*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Введение в JavaScript
    <ul>
      <li>Размещение скриптов на HTML-страницах</li>
      <li>Синтаксис языка</li>
      <li>Типы данных
        <ul>
          <li>Объект Global</li>
          <li>Оборачивание (wrapping), изменчивость (mutability)</li>
          <li>Преобразование типов, основные методы: toString, valueOf</li>
          <li>Инициализация объектов, массивов и функций</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>Переменные и область видимости</li>
      <li>Операторы языка</li>
      <li>Выражения: условия и циклы</li>
      <li>Операторы перехода (label, break, continue, return)</li>
      <li>Исключения и обработка ошибок: try/catch/finally, throw</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Работа с объектами в JavaScript
    <ul>
      <li>Создание объектов</li>
      <li>Доступ к свойствам: опрос, добавление, удаление и перечисление свойств</li>
      <li>Массивы, методы работы с массивами</li>
      <li>Функции и передача параметров</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>JavaScript в браузере
    <ul>
      <li>Очередность выполнения скриптов</li>
      <li>DOM: объектная модель документа
        <ul>
          <li>Основные объекты браузера, объект Window</li>
          <li>Объект Document: поиск и работа с элементами</li>
          <li>Настройка и изменение стилей документа</li>
          <li>Обработка событий</li>
          <li>Графика: элемент canvas</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Работа с формами: валидация данных, регулярные выражения</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`(*1)` - если существующий на странице элемент пытаются вставить куда-нибудь в другое место, он не копируется - а просто переносится. Поэтому все элементы списка заново перевставляются уже в нужном порядке.